# Searching in a grouped list taking lot of time in iOS of Xamarin forms project

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, searchbar

I have a search bar and a list view in xaml.

Below is my search bar text changed code:

```
viewModel.FilterList(searchTicket.Text);
```

In my ViewModel class:

I have an observableCollection list as below:

```
public ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Ticket>> TicketList
{
    get { return _ticketList; }
    set { _ticketList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

public void FilterList(string text)
{
     GroupCollections(TicketListNew.Where(Tl => Tl.CustomerName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower());
}

 private void GroupCollections(List<Ticket> ticketListNew)
 {
     var sorted = from ticket in ticketListNew
                     orderby ticket.DelPUDate
                     group ticket by GetTicketDate(ticket.DelPUDate) into ticketListGroup
                     select new Grouping<string, Ticket>(ticketListGroup.Key, ticketListGroup);
      if (TicketList == null) TicketList = new ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, Ticket>>(sorted);
      else
      {
          TicketList.Clear();
          foreach (var item in sorted)
          {
              TicketList.Add(item);
           }
        }
    }
```

when the code goes to else part it is taking lot of time to process to fetch the data and populate the list (list gets stuck for 5-6 seconds).
Whereas same code works perfect in android device.

In android, suppose if we click on 15th list item, it opens a page. And on coming back from the page the list stays on that 15th list item.
whereas in iOS, list gets stuck for 5-6 seconds and scrolls itself to the top.

Do I need to do anything to work as same on iOS device?

Any Help?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I still could not figure out the issue. Now, I changed the code to search the list only when entry has two letters in it. Hence the list would be small and there is no lag in filtering the list